# OSX Server 10.8.2 - Change domain password (command line)

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-server

How do i go about changing the domain password for a user?
Assuming i'm running a admin account, is there a `command` or method to change a users password without a GUI?

Also, previous password is unknown so `sudo passwd` doesn' work (it requires me to have the old passwod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being an admin (or root) on the local computer is irrelevant to the domain controller -- in order to reset a domain user's password, you need to authenticate to the domain controller using domain admin credentials. You can do this from OS X with the `dscl` command. Here's an example of resetting the password for the user "fred" in the LDAP domain named "domaincontroller.com", by authenticating as the domain admin "diradmin":

```
dscl -u diradmin -p /LDAPv3/domaincontroller.com -passwd /Users/fred
```

Note that `-p` tells it to prompt for the domain admin's password; `-P "password"` would specify the admin's password on the command line, which is not recommended for security reasons.  Also, if you're not sure what the appropriate nodename for the domain is (`/LDAPv3/domaincontroller.com` in the above example), check the user's meta node location:

```
dscl /Search -read /Users/fred | grep "^AppleMetaNodeLocation"
```

Comment: Forgot this thread, i solved it in a similar manner :)
Apple should learn a thing or two about standards tho ._.